# Get js and css from gem without pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline, redmine

I created gem for plugins for Redmine. 
Nowadays I have task for adding some javascript and css file to my gem, but I don't know how I can include this file to plugin. Because Redmine didn't use pipeline I can't use:

```
//= require my_redmine_gem
```

What are the right way for this task?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Maybe copy to plugin folder with rake or generator?

Answer (score 1):

There is a hook in Redmine which allow you to add any resource your plugin need.

You can use it this way:

```
module MyRedminePlugin
  class Hooks < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
    #adds our css on each page
    def view_layouts_base_html_head(context)
      stylesheet_link_tag("my_css_file", :plugin => "my_redmine_plugin")
    end
  end
end
```

Then you have to put your css and js files in your plugin in the assets/stylesheets or assets/javascripts folders.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Redmine, but I've created a Gem before, [with its own asset payload](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler/tree/master/app/assets):

[image]

If you hook into your Rails app properly, this will append the assets into your own asset pipeline, allowing you to reference them as if they were stored locally.

You can either put them into:

```
-- [gem root]
|-- assets
  |-- images
    |-- [here]
|-- vendor
  |-- assets
    |-- [or here]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if I right You use pipeline too: config.assets.precompile += %w(exception_handler/error.css)

Comment: Yep but the app's functionality is not dependent on it. Besides, the precompile command is in the engine so I don't see how it would hold much of a difference?